# delayed_job: attribute accessor values are not stored in delayed_jobs table in rails 3 after upgrade from rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

How we did this in rails2 was: For a job class we set a bunch of attr_accessor methods for the job object and enqueue the object into delayed_jobs table and those accessor values are stored in the table as well. (we were using delayed_job 2.0.3)

But in rails3 even though we follow the same procedure as in rails2, the attr_accessor values are not stored into the table. Can anybody tell me how we persist the accessor values into the table with the new delayed_job gem(3.0.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the problem is with the psych parser which takes into consideration only the database attributes for a model object and doesn't take into consideration instance and class variables. Here's a more precise answer for the question: [YAML, delayed_job : Psych vs Syck. How to make pysch read attr_accessors for a ruby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125777/yaml-delayed-job-psych-vs-syck-how-to-make-pysch-read-attr-accessors-for-a-r)